# How to prove that some number is the minimum steps required to prove a certain logical statement?

Tags: alternative-proof

Let's say we're working under the framework of classical logic, and I want to prove a statement by just using the laws of predicate logic (in which case we may define a step as an application of a single logical law), for example to prove $(A\,\texttt{AND}\,B)\,\texttt{AND}\, C$ given $A,B$ and $C$ one only needs these steps:

```
A. [given]
B. [given]
C. [given]
From A, B: deduce A AND B. [CONJUNCTION INTRODUCTION]
From A AND B, C: deduce (A AND B) AND C. [CONJUNCTION INTRODUCTION]
QED!
```

But how can one prove, given an arbitrary situation, that $n$ is the minimal number of steps required to prove something? (I'm especially interested for a practical way for these types of elementary logic questions)

Let me give an example outside the purview of classical logic, let's say you want to prove that the row operation 'interchange two rows' is equivalent to a combination of 'multiply a row by a non-zero constant' and 'add a multiple of a row to another row', then you can do so by using 4 steps, but how can I prove that this is the smallest number for which a proof is possible?

Comment: Sorry for the flawed tag, I don't know what to put.

Comment: Please review "Information Theory" and entropy related to that.  That might give you partial answer to your question.

Comment: @SatishRamanathan thanks can you suggest any reference, introductory book, other answer on SE where information theory is used to answer such a question?

Comment: https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/informationtheory/moderninfotheory/v/information-entropy